# Common categories for two custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

can I use a category as common for more than one custom post types? In this case same category will have more than one type of posts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), the second argument is the `object_type` argument, which accepts either a string or an array. You can pass this an array of objects to apply the taxonomy to, and it will be common between those. So, for example: `array( 'cpt_slug', 'post' )` would give you a common taxonomy between `cpt_slug` and `post`.

If you want to add the existing taxonomies to a new post type, you can use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type)